# console.write("\r") not displaying elements in same line on server

Tags: c#

I am trying to print the count of directories in a loop and want to have the output displayed in the same line but with the value changes. I used the below code which works fine in my local system, but when I run same code on the windows server 2012 R2 this displays in separate line for each directory.

```
Console.Write("\r[ {0} Directories scan complete ] [ {1} files scan complete ] [ Percentage completed {2}% ]", directoryCount.ToString(), fileCount.ToString(), percentage.ToString());
```

**Local machine output:**

[image]

**Server output:**

```
[ 1 Directories complete ] [ 10 files scan complete ] [ Percentage completed 1% ]
[ 2 Directories complete ] [ 26 files scan complete ] [ Percentage completed 2% ]
[ 3 Directories complete ] [ 39 files scan complete ] [ Percentage completed 3% ]
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing your "local machine" is a console and the "server" is a redirected stream?

Comment: Would .Writeline work for you without the return ("\r") char.

Comment: `"\r"` is a carriage return, not a newline;.  `"\n"` is a newline.  Use `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @Amy In the Windows console, \r returns the character to the start of the current line, so you can use that to overwrite the line. Of course that only works in the console: if you're redirecting it to a file, then you'll just see a `\r` character followed by the new line.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I have this code in an exe file. So i am running the exe to get the output where the local machine is working as expected.

Comment: How are you getting the server output?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Looks like this has to do with the console window size to display the output. My local has higher width size and server has less width size. Since the server had less width size it was displaying in each line. Setting the width size for the console in the code fixed my problem.

Comment: Ah, rats, I was going to ask what the console width was! But I assumed it would still overwrite each line even if the line wrapped to the next one.

Comment: @RufusL: Exactly :-).. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of relying on `\r`, it may be better to capture `Console.CursorTop` on the line that you want to output, and then use `Console.SetCursorPosition` to set the cursor to the beginning of that line each time before outputting your results:

For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Capture the current line number
    var lineNo = Console.CursorTop;

    int i = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        // Set the cursor position before outputting our progress
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, lineNo);
        Console.Write($"Iterations performed: {i++}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Sure. I have no idea if this will actually solve the issue since `\r` seems to work for everyone else, but this shouldn't be any *worse* :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following. \r will return the cursor back to the beginning of current line. So, you can use -3 to left align the new input.

```
Console.Write("\r[ {0, -3} Directories scan complete ] [ {1, -3} files scan complete ] [ Percentage completed {2, -3}% ]", directoryCount.ToString(), fileCount.ToString(), percentage.ToString());
```

or you can try `StringBuilder.Append` and then write to the console.

```
sb.Append('\r')
```

or more readable:

```
const char LF = '\r';
sb.Append(data); // your current data
sb.Append (LF);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!